# Is there a simpler way of enqueuing scripts for multiple page templates in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, templates

Besides the standard `page.php` in my Wordpress theme, I have an additional page template called `full-page.php`.
I want to enqueue an additional script ( `script-4.js` ) in `full-page.php` that I don't want to enqueue in the default template. At the moment I have enqueued them using the method below, with `if` and `else` statements – the same way in which my stylesheets are enqueued.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without enqueuing everything twice? For example, in `full-page.php`, is it possible for me to just enqueue `script-4.js` whilst getting it to automatically take scripts 1, 2 and 3 from the default template?

```
function enqueue_my_styles_and_scripts() {  

if (is_page_template('page-templates/full-page.php')) { 

    wp_enqueue_script(
    'mytheme-script-1',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-1.js' ); 

    wp_enqueue_script(
    'mytheme-script-2',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-2.js' );

    wp_enqueue_script(
    'mytheme-script-3',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-3.js' );

    wp_enqueue_script(
    'mytheme-script-4',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-4.js' );

}

else {

    wp_enqueue_script(
    'mytheme-script-1',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-1.js' );


    wp_enqueue_script(
    'mytheme-script-2',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-2.js' );


    wp_enqueue_script(
    'mytheme-script-3',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-3.js' );

}   

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_styles_and_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
function enqueue_my_styles_and_scripts() {  

wp_enqueue_script(
    'mytheme-script-1',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-1.js' ); 

wp_enqueue_script(
    'mytheme-script-2',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-2.js' );

wp_enqueue_script(
    'mytheme-script-3',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-3.js' );

if (is_page_template('page-templates/full-page.php')) {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'mytheme-script-4',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-4.js' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_styles_and_scripts' );
```

Comment: Hi Loic, thank you, that worked. It didn't even occur to me to write it that way, as for some reason I thought that an `if` statement always had to be followed by an `else`.

Comment: Ah I think I see what you mean, so can I write something like `if (is_default_template() && !(is_page_template('page-templates/full-page.php')) {` and make a script apply to the default template, and every other custom page template I have, apart from full-page.php which is given the `isn't`value above?

Comment: Yes for example… I don't know which template you want and which you dont want as condition, but there is a lot of possibilities in if condition using `&&`, `||`, `!`, `!=`, `==`… see [PHP logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).